# How do I make a symbolic link to list of directories?

Tags: linux, bash

I must move my `$HOME/.directories` because I have wrong partitioning.

I moved to a another partition with much more free space. But I wanna make a symbolic links, but I cant. Because when I try something like:

```
for file in `ls -la | awk '{print$09}'`; do sudo ln -sf "$PWD/$file" /home/inukaze/$file; done

usage: sudo [-D level] -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid]
usage: sudo -l[l] [-AknS] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-U user name] [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-C fd] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [VAR=value] [-i|-s]
            [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-C fd] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid] file ...
```

I need the full path for correct read of symbolic links. And I this is not working. How I can make a list of folders begins with “dot” (`.`), and make symbolic links inside my home directory?

Okey friends i have try with :

1 :

```
for file in `ls -la "$PWD" | awk '{print$09}' | grep "^\."` ; do `sudo ln -sf $("$PWD/$file") $"("/home/inukaze/$file")"` ; done
```

2 :

```
MYDIR="/media/Compartido/.linux/Home/Inukaze"
DIRS=`ls -la "$MYDIR" | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'`
for DIR in $DIRS ; do sudo ln -sf "$PWD/$DIRS" "/home/inukaze/$DIRS" ; done
```

3 :

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 |while read DIRNAME; do sudo ln -s "${DIRNAME}" /home/inukaze/"${DIRNAME}"; done
```

But with the Three Methods , i got the same result , much bad symbolic links and just 6 are right . i dont understand why.

something are wrong , i start to think is in the

> "sudo ln -s $Varible" $Destiny ; done"

well . another ideas ???

Comment: I'm not sure that e.g. `ssh` will allow you to use a symlink for `.ssh`. It's pretty strict about that.

Comment: Also, have you considered just changing your home directory? You can do this with the `usermod` command, assuming you have root access.

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s dotglob
cp -s * ~inukaze
```

Comment: This will symlink all directories and files, dot or not.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. Not 100% clear what you are trying to achieve or what it’s not working, but I wrote this to attempt to debug based on your sample code. Note I am using `echo` instead of `ln -s` for now as well as changing `file` to the uppercase `FILE` and wrapping in brackets as well as double quotes:

```
for FILE in `ls -la | awk '{print$09}'`;
do
  echo "${PWD}/${FILE}" /home/inukaze/"${FILE}"
done
```

And on my local system—Mac OS X 10.9—it outputs:

```
/Users/jake/.bash_history /home/inukaze/.bash_history
/Users/jake/.bashrc /home/inukaze/.bashrc
/Users/jake/.cache /home/inukaze/.cache
/Users/jake/.gitk /home/inukaze/.gitk
/Users/jake/.htoprc /home/inukaze/.htoprc
/Users/jake/.mysql_history /home/inukaze/.mysql_history
etc…
```

So unclear how your script is not working? Do you only want directories? Or files?

**EDIT:** Original poster is looking to only symlink directories.  So try this using `find` instead:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 |\
  while read DIRNAME
  do
    echo "${DIRNAME}" /home/inukaze/"${DIRNAME}"
  done
```

In my case, it finds all directories in my current home directory like this and echoes the `/home/inukaze/"${DIRNAME}` right after that:

```
./.ssh /home/inukaze/./.ssh
./.subversion /home/inukaze/./.subversion
./.Trash /home/inukaze/./.Trash
./.Xcode /home/inukaze/./.Xcode
./Applications /home/inukaze/./Applications
./Desktop /home/inukaze/./Desktop
./Documents /home/inukaze/./Documents
etc…
```

In this example I am just using `echo` to test the overall logic. And that is using `find` with the `-type d` option which tells it to just find directories and `-maxdepth 1` which is connected to the maximum depth `find` should go. Doing `1` deep will not explore any directory deeper than the directory you are in.

Comment: Just Directores

i try with some commands like :

====================================================================

MYDIR="/media/Compartido/.linux/Home/Inukaze"
DIRS=`ls -la "$MYDIR" | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'`
for DIR in $DIRS ; do sudo ln -sf "$PWD/$DIRS" "/home/inukaze/$DIRS" ; done

====================================================================

 for file in `ls -la "$PWD" | awk '{print$09}' | grep "^\."` ; do `sudo ln -sf $("$PWD/$file") $"("/home/inukaze/$file")"` ; done

====================================================================

Well its not working i need it

Comment: Its equal , with this "find" , i replace echo "${DIRNAME}" /home/inukaze/"${DIRNAME}" with sudo ln -s "${DIRNAME}" /home/inukaze/"${DIRNAME}" . and with this too make much bad symbolic links and just 6 works.

Answer (score 0):

> how i can make a list of folders begins with "dot" (.)

```
shopt -s dotglob
echo .*/ # This glob matches only dot-directories; however that includes ./ and ../
```

> and make symbolic links inside my home directory?

```
shopt -s dotglob
for d in "$PWD"/.*/; do
  case "$d" in
    *./|*../) :;; # do nothing for these two directories
    *) ( cd && ln -s "$d" );;
  esac
done
```

The above is more verbose than [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23554859/418413), but also links only dot directories other than `.` and `..`. It also will work on BSD/OSX.

Comment: @JakeGould my understanding is that OP moved dotdirs to another directory (on another filesystem) and wants to create symlinks at `$HOME` to the new dotdirs to keep apps functioning.

Comment: @JakeGould well, it probably is, but when you get partitioning wrong you have to jump through all kinds of hoops. This could be a temporary measure.

Comment: Yes long time ago , i put wrong sizes in the root partition . well

for d in "$PWD"/.*/; do case "$d" in *./|*../) :;; *) ( sudo ln -s "$d" "/home/inukaze/");; esac; done

this work more near , but just 6 symbolic links works , the anothers dont have the full path for origin to destiny.

with your command :

for d in "$PWD"/.*/; do case "$d" in *./|*../) :;; *) ( cd && ln -s "$d" );; esac; done

long list with "ln: falied to make symbolic link «./.yabause»: the file exist"

Comment: @inukaze sounds like `.yabause` already exists in the home directory.

Comment: that its the problem , because that dont exist , until i use a command like

find . -type d -maxdepth 1 |while read DIRNAME; do sudo ln -s "${DIRNAME}" /home/inukaze/"${DIRNAME}"; done

but this dont have the full path , its just ".yabause" and this make with the anothers directories , except with 6 , but i really dont understand why

Comment: If the system thinks it exists, it exists. Examine the actual behavior of the above commands by using `set -x` in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with

**`ls -la | awk '{print$09}'`**

Because with this all folder finish with "/" and the "ln -sf" not create a symbolic links if you add / in the finish

i try with

**`ls -la | awk '{print$09}' | sed 's/\/*$//`**

just for remove the last character in ls -la

Okey i think i solved

i go to my backup folder , in this case /media/Compartido/.linux/Home/Inukaze

**`$ for file in $(ls -la | awk '{print$09}' | sed 's/\/*$//') ; do sudo ln -sf "$PWD/$file" "/home/inukaze/$file" ; done`**

**`ln: <</home/inukaze/./.>> : cannot overwrite a directory`**

**`ln: <</home/inukaze/../..>> : cannot overwrite a directory`**

---

and ready all symbolic links are correctly created :=)